# VirtualBox display ratio 26:9, not 16:9

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS and just upgraded my VirtualBox to 5.2.12 with the new guest additions.  Before, I had a nice Windows client that had a 16:9 display ratio, perfect for filling my 27" monitor.

Now, however, my display ratio seems stuck at a ridiculous 26:9, meaning that for the 1920px width to fit, the vertical ends up 675px, with large unusable gray bands on the top and bottom of the screen.  I can use "scale" to make those disappear, but the stretching is so severe that a circle turns into a squooshed oval.

I suspect, not sure, that this is somehow caused by my having a second monitor that works great in Linux, but which makes the width of the screen appear longer to the Windows client.  It worked fine though before, so perhaps somehow there's a problem in the new version of VirtualBox?

I've tried the in-Windows display options and nothing really fixes this, and I've tried in the Display section of VirtualBox for some tweak, again, with no results.

Anyone know what's going on and how to force my Windows client to see a normal 16:9 ratio display?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues after upgrades; what normally helps is

1. switch the virtual box to scaled mode and back to full screen mode (Host+C; Host+F), or
2. reinstall the virtual box guest additions again, and reboot.

Also, make sure you have allocated enough video memory in the virtual box's settings.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your current issue you will need to remove your current version of guest additions from the guest and host, then reinstall it.

---

To stop the issue in the future:

Try installing [DKMS](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/).

DKMS doesn't actually resize the screen but every time there is a kernel update  you don't have to rebuild guest additions.